# How to implement WebVeiw in app "kotlin"?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview

Trying to implement webView with kotlin but getting error
Error 1 - java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.webkit.WebView.loadUrl(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at com.abc.MainActivity.onNavigationItemSelected
Error 2 - E/cr_PlatformSer-Internal: UsageReporting query failed
E/cr_PlatformSer-Internal: Unable to determine Safe Browsing user opt-in preference

MainActivity.kt-

```
 val webView: WebView? = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webView)

            webView?.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
            setContentView(R.layout.fragment_privacy)
            val url: String = intent.getStringExtra("https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/") ?: "Privacy"
```

privacyfragment.kt-

```
class privacyfragment {
        fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View? {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment 
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_privacy, container, false)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to look for `R.id.webView` before you've set a layout on your Activity with `setContentView`. You need to do it in this order:

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_privacy)
val webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webView)
```

That way `findViewById` can access the Activity's `view` (which has now been created) and do the search. Also, if you expect the `WebView` to be there, there's no need to make `webView` nullable - if it *is* null and causes a crash, it's because you have a problem that needs to be fixed.

---

But if you're trying to add a `Fragment`, calling `setContentView` with the fragment's layout XML won't do it - that just puts the same views in the `Activity`, there's no `Fragment` there. Read [this guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments) to learn about `Fragments` and the different ways you can add them and navigate between them.

If you're creating a `Fragment` that holds your `WebView`, you should do all its setup (including the `findViewById`) inside the `Fragment`. Trying to poke at it from the `Activity` (and all the coordination that involves) will cause you a lot of problems. Your `Activity` can always call a function on the `Fragment` to request "load this URL", the `Fragment` itself should be the thing that talks directly to the `WebView`

Comment: Finally I was able to solve the problem thank you so much!!  @cactustictacs

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it as

MainActivity.kt

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_privacy)
val webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webView)
webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
            webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
            webView.loadUrl("add your url here")
```